# configuring Quartz CMT jobStore using Spring datasource

Tags: spring, datasource, jndi, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to confugre Quartz JobStoreCMT and use Spring's datasource as the managed datasource. Here is my Spring's config file with the datasource definition:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>
```

Here is my quartz.properties:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties: false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = managedTXDS
org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource = qzDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix: QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered: false

#============================================================================
# Configure Datasources  
#============================================================================
org.quartz.dataSource.managedTXDS.jndiURL=java:comp/env/jdbc/dataSource

org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema
org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.user: user
org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.password: pwd
org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.maxConnections: 5
org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.validationQuery=select 0 from dual
```

when I run my unit test that tries to initialize Scheduler I'm getting the following error:

```
2011-07-20 21:38:22,477 [main] ERROR org.quartz.utils.JNDIConnectionProvider - Error  looking up datasource: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or  system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
...
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'managedTXDS': java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:comp/env/jdbc/dataSource' javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:comp/env/jdbc/dataSource' javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial]
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:726)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.executeInLock(JobStoreCMT.java:231)
```

So, is this a problem with specifying the org.quartz.dataSource.managedTXDS.java.naming.factory.initial and/or org.quartz.dataSource.managedTXDS.jndiURL=java:comp/env/jdbc/dataSource ?

If it is the JNDI factory setting that is missing - what should be the value for Spring?

thanks!
Marina

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look @

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/LocalDataSourceJobStore.html

Set this as

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I tried that and did get a bit further now. The next error I'm getting is this:  actually, see my answer posted separately - it is hard to add all formatted code and text in comments...

Comment: no need in this, because from link above: "This JobStore will be used if SchedulerFactoryBean's "dataSource" property is set."